# Celeron n3150 powerful enough to run Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: hardware

The specs recommend a 2Ghz, dual-core processor.  The n3150 is 1.6Ghz but has four cores.  Would that compensate for the deficit in speed?

Answer (score 0):

Those are recommended specs, but yes, the N3150 should be plenty powerful to run Ubuntu relatively smoothly. If you wish for a lighter distribution I recommend Lubuntu.

Cores do not make up performance deficits in most cases. Cores simply allow additional threads/tasks to be run at one time, but do not speed up a single task/thread. The N3150, despite its 4 cores, is still rather slow for intensive tasks such as games and/or video/photo editing.